# Why does padding property make elements larger?

Tags: html, css, padding

I have a div with a letter :

HTML

```
<div>A</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #CC0000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 50px;
  padding: 0px 30px 0px 10px /* I want to move my letter with it */
}
```

The letter moves due to padding property, but it also makes the square larger.
Why does padding transform the square into a rectangle?

JSF : http://jsfiddle.net/fnBaD/1

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/cssboxmodel/boxmodelannot.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding is always applied 'within' the element. Hence,

```
padding:5px;
```

is effectively adding `5px` on all four sides 'within' an element.

Hence, the `padding` property makes elements larger.

Comment: 'Always'? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

The standard 'box model' does NOT include padding/borders into width/height calculations

By adding the `box-sizing:border-box` property it will force the browser to INCLUDE the padding/borders in the dimensions

It's often seen in a universal selector

```
* {
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Answer (score 0):

Padding is considered to be part of the element it is applied to. This is why the element gets larger.