# Padding property doesn't add spacing

Tags: html, css, padding

I [recently realised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24354838/why-does-padding-property-make-elements-larger.) that padding property adds spacing between the content and the border of this content.
I was testing this property when I discovered an instance where padding doesn't add spacing.

I have a paragraph

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

and some styling

```
p {
    background: red;
    color: white;
    border: dashed 2px blue;
    margin-left: 44px   
}
```

Result ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5fYL/1/))

[image]
Then I add `padding: 49px` to CSS. Logically, I shoud get something like it [image]

but finally I obtain it ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5fYL/2/))
[image]
As we can see, the text moves, but the red spacing isn't added. Why?

PS : maybe I express myself badly, I'm sorry about it

Comment: Remove the `margin-left`? Your expectation is wrong, your first image already shows the red block has moved to the right. With the padding it will not magically move back to the left.

Comment: *"..Logically, I shoud get something like it .."*: Better remove `padding-left` then.

Comment: You have margin left and padding left, the white space is the margin, and the extra space before the text is the padding. Assuming you only added padding left. If you actually added `padding: 49px` then your image is not showing it. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Huangism, I forgot margin-left property in my CSS ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `margin-left`. [Difference between Margins and Paddings.](http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-between-margins-padding-css/)

Remove it:

CSS

```
p {
background: red;
color: white;
border: dashed 2px blue;
padding-left: 49px
}
```

[In this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5fYL/3/)

No more space :)

Answer (score 0):

The red is the `background-color` which is also by default painted into the `padding` area, and not the `margin`. The behavior you are seeing is correct.

If you don't want the background painted into the padding area, you can set:

```
background-clip: content-box;
```

However I think that only works in IE9 and up, so if you need to support IE8, then you can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

The result you get is correct.

Margin - adds space outside your box

Border - adds a border around your box

Padding - adds space between content and border

Look up "css box model" on google for more.

K

Answer (score 0):

I have not understand what you are trying to do but i guess you want this

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    p 
    {
        background: red;
        color: white;
        border: dashed 2px blue;
        /* display: inline-block; */
        padding-left: 49px

    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```